# How to copy one cluster in same host to another location and initialize it as new cluster

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu

I have one postgresql database. Now I need to stop and copy this database $PGDATA directory to another location and then initialize it as a new cluster under another name on the same host. As you know I can initialize the new cluster with initdb tool. But I do not want to initialize the new empty cluster but want to initialize the existing cluster copied by me from another cluster on Ubuntu. Thank you very much

Comment: If you are copying  the entire `$PGDATA` you don't need to initialize it. It should be enough to just do `pg_ctl start -D <new  $PGDATA>`. You will have to change the `port` the new instance is listening on so as not to clash with the original instance. As always assume the worst and make sure you have  an up to date backup of original database before proceeding. Depending on what your goals are you may also want to look at [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html).

Comment: But on Ubuntu when we just copy $PGDATA to another location, there is the separate config files for new cluster will not created. For example if the first cluster location is /var/lib/postgresql/14/main and this cluster config file placed in /etc/postgresql/14/main

If we copy this directory "/var/lib/postgresql/14/main" inside to another directory there are will not created a new directory for config files of that new cluster. How can I register a new cluster on same host in this case?

Comment: I have never done this but it looks you can 1) Use `pg_backupcluster` to backup existing cluster to `/var/backups/`, then 2) Use `pg_restorecluster [options] version cluster backup
` to restore to a new cluster by providing appropriate `version` and `cluster`  names to command. See the `man` entries for each command for more information.